# what would be the equivalent of this in php to connect to socket and send a message

Tags: php, sockets

what would be the equivalent of this in php to connect to socket and send a message

```
var msg = "hello Motto";
var wsUri = "ws://mylocalserver:9001/ab/server.php";    
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 
    websocket.send(msg);
```

this works great its in javascript and I have a listener file that shows the message. I would like to do the exact same thing with php I am confused I looked up plenty of documentation online but nothing seems straightforward any help please

here is the php code I put together but its not working for some reasons I dont receive the ping on the other end:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

$msg = "Ping !";
$len = strlen($msg);

socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, 'ws://mylocalserver:9001/ab/server.php', 9001);
socket_close($sock);
```

this is the part that fails :
this works:

```
socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, 'mylocalserver', 9001);
```

but this doesnt work : 
  socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, 'mylocalserver/ab/server.php', 9001);
the problem is i am using server.php to handle the messages sent. any ideas please?

Comment: start here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available. thats socket send. thats why I said its confusing I was hoping for an example of some sort. thank you Dagon

Comment: example: http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: I did some tests and updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## php websocket server example

These are just the bare bones

```
//Create TCP/IP sream socket and return the socket resource
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Bind the source address
socket_bind($socket, 'localhost');

// Listen to incoming connection
socket_listen($socket);

// Accept new connections
socket_accept($socket);

// Handshake
$secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
$secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
$upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
"Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
"Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
"WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
"WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/deamon.php\r\n".
"Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
```

---

Your better off using a library to do this in php like this one: https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets

If that's too much to learn, [you can have a look at this tutorial](http://www.techzonemind.com/php-websocket-library-two-way-real-time-communication/) which shows you how to build a real time chat using websockets. (this also uses a websocket library for php)

Comment: I think that will do it thanks !